# How do I simply take user's first name and last name, store it in a database and greet the user by calling his full name using django?

Tags: django

```
from django.db import models

class Username(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

def __str__(self):
    return self.first_name+' '+self.last_name
```

I have made models and have settings and all things migrated. I tried searching on web how to do this simple thing but I am getting very detailed answers with stuff I don't want, I just want a simple page that will greet the user with his full name pulled from the database

Comment: You can process such a request in a view and then send the first and last name to a html template and use template language to insert that user's name in the html.

Comment: Please consider passing some tutorials!

Answer (score 0):

Django has a built in user model that includes first and last name. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#user-objects) on that.

When the user is logged in, you can call `request.user.first_name`, which will display the first name stored in the database.